# Setting a device target on google ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to create a campaign that must target mobile devices only, using the google ads API client library in python. The documentation says that I have to modify the DeviceInfo criteria, but that attribute is immutable.
This is my code rn:

```
campaign_service = client.get_service("CampaignService")
    campaign_criterion_service = client.get_service("CampaignCriterionService")

    # Create the campaign criterion.
    campaign_criterion_operation = client.get_type("CampaignCriterionOperation")
    campaign_criterion = campaign_criterion_operation.create
    campaign_criterion.campaign = campaign_service.campaign_path(
        customer_id, campaign_id
    )
    
    campaign_criterion.device = client.enums.DeviceEnum.MOBILE
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For most of Enums you have to use the `.type_` after the value you wanna set.
So you should use:

```
campaign_criterion.device.type_ = client.enums.DeviceEnum.MOBILE
```

A nice advice is to download library code and goes into reading that.